# search function(react js) just search between first 8 posts instead of search between all posts

Tags: node.js, reactjs

search function in react just search between first 8 posts instead of search between all posts(there is 220 posts in website)

i do not really understand , i tried every solution . but nothing at all

I really need help

this is my search file

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import tw, { styled } from 'twin.macro';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../../common/LoadingSpinner';
import PostsList from '../../../common/PostsList';
import { useGetPostsQuery } from '../../../core/features/posts/postsApiSlice';
import Postslistxx from '../../Tag/Postlistsxx';

const Posts = ({ value }) => {
  const { data: posts, isLoading } = useGetPostsQuery(null, {
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  });
  const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(posts?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [value, posts]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
  ) : (
    filteredPosts && <Postslistxx posts={filteredPosts} enableImages={false} />
  );
};

const Wrapper = tw.div`bg-blue`;

export default Posts;
```

and this is my postlistxxx.js file

```
import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import Placeholder from '../../../src/common/Placeholder/Placeholder';
import Post from '../../common/PostsList/components/Post';

const Postslistxx = ({ posts, filteredTag, filteredPosts,toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
    {posts?.length > 0 ? (
      posts.map((post, i) => (
        <Post
          post={post}
          isFirstPost={enableImages && i === 0}
          filteredTag={filteredTag}
          key={nanoid()}
          toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
        />
      ))
    ) : (
      <Placeholder />
    )}
  </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = tw.div`w-full`;

export default Postslistxx;
```

and this is my postlist file that in this file i fetch all the posts into main page of website

```
import { nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import tw from "twin.macro";
import Advertise from "../../pages/PostPage/components/Advertise";
import Placeholder from "../Placeholder";
import Post from "./components/Post";
import rehypeVideo from "rehype-video";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LoadingSpinner from "../LoadingSpinner/LoadingSpinner";





// import AutoDarkMode from 'auto-dark-mode';
// const theme = null; // will apply the default one
// // some elemens may got corrupted so double rotate them 
// const doubleRotatedElements = ['img', 'video']; 
// new AutoDarkMode(theme, doubleRotatedElements);
  






// import ArticleSkeleton from './ArticleSkeleton';
const PostsList = ({ filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  const advertise = async () => {
    window?.EventBus?.emit("reset-ads");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    advertise();
  }, []);

  const [posts, setposts] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setisLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        let skip = posts.length;
        // await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=5&skip=${skip}`)
        await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=6&skip=${skip}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => setposts([...posts, ...result]));
      }
    };

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const html = document.documentElement;
      const body = document.body;
      const windowheight =
        "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : html.offsetHeight;

      const docHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
      );

      const windowBottom = windowheight + window.pageYOffset;
      if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
        console.log("we reached the bottom");
        fetchAgain();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [posts]);




  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      // const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts`)
      const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts");
      
      const data = await res.json();

      setposts(data);
      console.log(data);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);



  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {
        posts?.length  ? (
          posts.map((post, i) => (
            <>
              <>
                <Post
                  post={post}
                  isFirstPost={enableImages && i++}
                  filteredTag={filteredTag}
                  key={nanoid()}
                  toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
                />
                <Advertise />
              </>
            </>
          ))
        ) : (
          <>
            <LoadingSpinner />
          </>
        )
        // (

        //   <Placeholder />

        // )
      }
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = tw.div`w-full`;

export default PostsList;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

after we discussed, I saw the problem is that is your posts is already just 8 posts here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // posts here are only 8 they need to be 220 
    setFilteredPosts(posts?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [value, posts]);
```

*so you have 2 chocies:*

1. Debug this file to figure out why they are only 8:

   ```
   import { useGetPostsQuery } from '../../../core/features/posts/postsApiSlice';
   // this shouldn't be only 8 posts
   const { data: posts, isLoading } = useGetPostsQuery(null, {
       refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
   });
   ```
2. Refetch the posts again in your search file in Posts component ***and I don't recommend it***, you can do this:

   ```
   const [reFetchPosts, setReFetchPosts] = useState(null);
   useEffect(() => {
       setTimeout(async () => {
       // const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts`)
       const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts");
       const data = await res.json();
           setReFetchPosts(data);
       }, 2000);
   }, []);

   useEffect(() => {
       setFilteredPosts(reFetchPosts?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
   }, [value, reFetchPosts]);
   ```

Comment: no i mean , website has posts in it , there is 220 posts, but it just search in 8 posts , i mean if u search for css , it should shows the posts include css word in it , but it not shows , but if  u search for another word it shows , see this u will understand https://babacode.ir/search . if u see this page , it shows 8 posts for search . but in main page of website there is 220 posts this is the main page https://babacode.ir/

Comment: Inside the same use effect try to console log your posts and see how much there

Comment: 220 . bit in search page just shows 8 post , and u can only search between 8 post and search works for that 8 posts . but search not work for the 220 posts . do u know what i mean

Comment: Yes I got the idea, let me check the code

Comment: please save this puzzle for me if u need more information ask , i am stocked on this

Comment: I will help, I will edit my original comment because it's easier to write there .. keep watching

Comment: ok i will wait for u , i have hope , thank you man ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253382/discussion-between-aous-mohammad-and-samurai).